# Can I hide the contents of a specific private repository on GitHub?

Tags: github

There is one project of my private repository GitHub.

What I want is to hide the number of Contributions in this repository from others.

Is this impossible?

The setting is already private, not public.
What I want is that people don't see the contention of this project.

Comment: If it's a private repository, how are other people able to see it anyway? Please clarify exactly what you mean. (Do you mean that it's shared with specific contributors, but you don't want them to be able to see each other's work?)

Comment: What's the use case here?

Answer (score 0):

No, not without effort - it's not a setting you can toggle on/off. The number of contributions is a public metric for all repositories if a user has access to it.

However you could follow the guidance here if you want to go the hard route: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104859/how-to-remove-or-hide-other-contributors-in-my-github